# Many routes with the same module

Tags: angular

I need to know what is the behavior of Angular 7 when I use the same module via lazy loading in different routes. Angular generate a new module independent of the others or reutilize the same module? 
For clarity, I put the following example:

I have a module that is an application for specific customer called CustomerModule.
I have many Customers that required the same application so I reutilize that module and create one route for each customer:

```
routes:[
   {
     path: "customer1",
     loadChildren: () => CustomerModule
   },
   {
     path: "customer2",
     loadChildren: () => CustomerModule
   },
    ..etc..
]
```

The behavior I expect is that Angular generates a new module independent of each others because I have many distinct configuration parameters for each customers (I manage this depending of the route).

Thank you so much.

Comment: based on your description, feel like you should not use multiple module instances, rather multiple component instances for different configs.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have multiple customers accessing the *same* functionality but through different path names? Would it be possible to use the same path names but a different parameter for different customers to prevent the need to have the repeated code?

Comment: I'm relatively certain that the module is the module, you won't get multiple "instances" of it. There is no code in a module, just its decorators.

Comment: Each customer need the same page personalized for them, that is colors, pictures, logo, etc. those parameters are obtained via request to an api and stored in a service that lives with the module.
Think of a presentation site for many different customers, in essence the site is the same but change some things for each one. I want to use one angular application for all of them.

Comment: Why not using a dynamic route like `/customer/:id`?

Comment: Thanks so much to all, I fell in more complexity than I really needed because the application will run for more than 1000 different customers so I thought a module with lazy loading could be the solution for not overload the application memory 
but simply using parameters in the route and getting the information dinamically based in the first path of the route I will  can resolve all of my projected problems. Thanks again to all you are guieded me in the right way.